# How to disable all list items in a dropdown, except one item

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I've a dropdown list having 50+ list items. But in some situations I need to enable only one item keeping all the others in a disabled state. I can disable or enable a list item simply by

```
mydropdown.Items.FindByValue("dq").Enabled = True
```

But how can I disable all the others in an easy way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, use a loop:

```
For Each item As ListItem In mydropdown.Items
    item.Enabled = item.Value = "dq"
Next
```

Comment: Sorry missed to mention. Any scope of without a loop.. Something like a NOT function

Comment: What means "any scope of without a loop"? You want to modify all items in the `DropDownList`, that means you have to  loop all items in the `DropDownList`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `For-Each` Loop to disable all items. And after the loop, enable the desired item:

```
For Each item In mydropdown.Items
    item.Enabled = False
Next
mydropdown.Items.FindByValue("itemToBeEnabled").Enabled = True
```

Comment: This loops the items twice, you just need one enumeration.

Comment: it doesn't loop them twice. the enabling is after the loop

Comment: But [`ListItemCollection.FindByValue`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/WebControls/ListItemCollection.cs,d966763826846658,references) also uses a loop to find that item.